# 5 minutes from now in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a section on my site that will display some information that will be available within 5 minutes (only within 5 minutes).

so I tried to do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE `end_date` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 8
```

the date is stored like so in end_date column:

```
2015-01-07 17:37:00
```

but i get no results on my page. no matter how far i back/forth in time/date.

could someone please advise on this?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: You have an extra open paren. Did you mean ``SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE `end_date` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 8`, and does that fix your problem?

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo or what, but there is a syntax error in your query: you're missing a bracket (`)`) which is being opened before `NOW()` but which is NOT being closed. Also, keep in mind that in this way you're refering to the **server time**, not the client's time.

Comment: Where's the PHP code?

Comment: Your math is backwards. it should be  `end_date <= NOW() + INTERVAL 5 minute`. you're saying "should be visible 5 minutes ago"

Comment: any reason for downvoting a valid question? or someone's been bored again and didn't have anything else to do?!?

Comment: @MarcB, when it comes to math, I feel "backward" LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this you missed the `)` and use `DATE_ADD`

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE  `end_date` <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
WHERE 
    `end_date` <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 8
```

Assuming its "within now and 5 minutes from now".

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * FROM tableName  WHERE 
>       `end_date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) ORDER BY rand() DESC LIMIT 8

Comment: date_sub not date_add as the other solutions say, also i think your < is backwards and should be >